# Can you add a separate switch (different light) to a 4 way switch?

Tags: multiway-switch

Can I add a circuit (new Light separate from existing) to a 4-way switch set up?  I  used what I thought was hot from a switch and the new light only works when certain switches are activated. The 4-way light can be on or off and the new circuit may work or may not.  I think I connected it to a traveler.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all switch boxes involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think I connected it to a traveler.**

That is the key right there. If you pulled power from a traveler then the new light will only work ~ 1/2 the time, depending on the position of the switches.

Keep in mind with any solution that you may need a larger box to install a 2nd switch due to box fill requirements.

There are 3 possible solutions:

- Switch at the source of power

Power typically takes one of two paths:

- Panel -> Switch 1 -> Switch 2 -> Switch 3...n -> Lights
- Panel -> Lights -> Switch 1 -> Switch 2 -> Switch 3...n

If you have the first setup then you can pull power from the *always hot* at Switch 1. You can't get it anywhere else because everywhere else is either *traveler* or *switched hot*.

If you have the second setup then you can pull power at the light fixture, but that would typically require running a new cable to get to the new switch.

- New cable

You can run a new cable from the panel or some other *always hot* location to the same box that has one of the existing switches. You must pull hot & neutral together - you can't piggyback on another neutral even if it is part of the same circuit (breaker), and you **must make sure that the neutrals don't get mixed up in the switch box**.

- Smart switches

You can replace the existing switches with smart switches that only need one wire instead of two travelers, freeing up a traveler to be used to power another set of switch(es)/lights. That works because smart switches use some variant of power line signaling or wireless signaling to do their job. No new wires to run, but more equipment costs, unless you were considering moving to smart switches anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for this excellent explanation!  I will look for smart switched tonight.

Comment: Dumb question.  Can I just replace the 3-way switches with smart switches and use one of the travelers as a hot?  Or do i need a Smart 4-way too?

Comment: Depends on the specific design. My guess is that most, if not all, smart switches are designed such that *all* switches for a particular light fixture be replaced with smart switches of the same type. Some have add-on switches that don't use any wires at all, which can make reuse of wires really simple. But each brand/product line is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a new circuit to a 4-way switch and expect it to work correctly. The 4-way works along side two 3-way switches. If you find the feed to the existing circuit, you could tap that to a new switch and light as long as the neutral is present and you have an extra gang in the box,

Answer (score 0):

Here is how 4-way switches are wired.

[image]

As you can see, you may have always-hot or neutral at a switch location, but you usually don't have both.   Those are the ones you need to branch off another switch.